# How to create xs:unique in XSD file?

Tags: xml, xsd

I want to create uniqueness of the attribute in xml.
In the list of passengers, each passenger has resnumb which should be unique:

```
<passengers>
    <passenger resnumb="872-AA">
    </passenger>
    <passenger resnumb="962-AA">
    </passenger>
</passengers>
```

How can I modify the attribute "resnumb" to make reservation number unique?

Comment: `xs:unique` belongs into a schema against which you could then validate your XML instance document. As for the schema language, see http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#specifyingUniqueness.

Comment: @MartinHonnen thanks for your reply. It was my mistake - I was thinking about xsd chema file of course :) But still I don't know how to implement xs:unique into xs:attribute. Do you know something about creating something like this?

Comment: Well, I have posted a link to a tutorial of the schema language showing how to do that. Read that and try to apply it to your XML, then if you get stuck, show us what you have tried by editing your question and I am sure we can help.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, i did it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34693570/xsunique-how-to-implement-into-attribute